# 宣言をした変数はいつまで残り続けるのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

宣言をした変数はいつまで残り続けるのでしょうか？
聞いたところ、その変数が所属する関数のスコープ内の処理が終了したときに、
変数も破棄される。
また、グローバル変数の場合はずっと常に残っているのでいつで使える

と聞いたのですが、この認識で正しいでしょうか？

JSについてです。

また、クラス上で宣言した変数の場合はすべてがグローバルになるのでどこからでも参照できるようですが、
グローバル変数と同じで破棄されることがなく常に存在すると考えてよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 回答に関する返信を質問内に記載しないようにしてください。ご自身の質問に対する回答にはコメントがつけられるはずですので、コメント機能を利用するようにしてください。質問の編集は回答やコメントの内容に基づいて「質問」の内容をより改善するためにご使用ください。

Comment: コメントだと改行などがなくなり見にくいのでむしろ編集してほしいといわれたので行ったのですが

Comment: 私にも経験があるので偉そうなことは言えないのですが、短いコメントではなかなか真意が伝わりにくかったのだろうと思います。例えば一旦もらえた回答が自分の意図するところではないときに、新しいコード等交えて質問の意図をより明確にしたい場合などには、質問の編集を行ってください。(最初のコメントの『「質問」の内容をより改善する』にあたります。)とにかく「質問」は質問内容を書くところであって、「回答」に対する「返信」を書く場所ではありません。メタ(このサイトの運営のあり方について意見交換する場所)の[このスレッド](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2463/13972)もご覧いただいた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: コメントにずらっと書くと見にくいですよね
だから編集にしてくれとあなたのように言ってきた人がいたのでそうしたんですよいったい誰のいう事にしたらいいのですか

Comment: [ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)や[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)は十分お読みいただいたでしょうか。どちらも世界でももっと信頼されるQ&Aサイトとなった本家英語版stackoverflowの方法論を元に日本語版スタック・オーバーフローの先人たちが改良を加えてきたものです。基本的には「Q&Aは質問者の課題を解決するとともに未来の読者にも有用なものとして蓄積されるべき」と言う理念に基づいています。その意図を汲んで行動していただきたいと言うのではダメでしょうか。「編集にしてくれ」と言った方も全てのコメントを編集で質問に混ぜ込めと言ったわけではないと思います。このサイトの利用方法についてさらなる疑問があれば、是非ともメタの方で問題提起してみてください。

Comment: 「返信」部分はロールバックさせていただきました。
質問として書かれた物であれば、それぞれ新しい別個の質問として投稿して下さい。
回答者にあてた感想のような物であって質問ではない、という事でしたら1〜2行以内にまとめて、回答に対するコメントになさるのがよいと思います。
ちなみに、「関数の中で定義した関数のことをクロージャ」というのは間違いです。

Answer (score 3):

#### ガベージコレクション(GC)

JavaScriptの変数のメモリ開放はECMAScript規定外の為、基本的に実装依存ですが、ガベージコレクション(GC)で回収されるまでは残るという考えが一般的です。
具体的には「関数スコープ内で該当変数を参照しなくなった場合」が該当し、それ以降はガベージコレクションで回収されるであろうと推測できます。

- [JavaScript - javascriptの変数のメモリへの割当について(72635)｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/72635)

#### グローバル変数

グローバル変数はページが `unload` されるまではメモリに残り続けます。
つまり、ページ遷移、[閉じる]、[更新]、[戻る]、[進む] のタイミングでメモリから破棄されます。

#### ローカル変数

ローカル変数は関数実行完了後、実装が任意のタイミングでメモリから破棄します。

```
<script>
(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
}(1));
// 関数実行終了時に匿名関数及びローカル変数xはメモリから破棄される
</script>
```

ただし、関数スコープがローカル変数を参照し続ける場合は別です。

```
<script>
var getX = (function (x) {  // 変数x は関数 getX から参照され続ける
  return function getX () { return x; };
}(1));
console.log(getX());
</script>
```

グローバル変数 getX はページが `unload` されるまでメモリに残り続けます。
関数 `getX` は変数 `x` を参照し続ける為、変数 `x` もページが `unload` されるまでメモリに残り続けます。
クロージャは関数を入れ子にするだけで簡単に生成されるものなので、メモリ節約の為には不必要に関数の階層を深くしない工夫が必要になります。

#### クラス

クラスも上述と考え方は同じです。
それがグローバル変数であったり、関数スコープから参照し続けるローカル変数でなければ、実行完了後にメモリから破棄されます。

Re: temestack さん